# Magento 2 : How to pass custom data in existing event

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am trying to pass

```
$pagedata  = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(array('name' => 'customdata'));
        $this->eventManager->dispatch('customer_login', ['customer' => $customerDataObject, 'obj' => $pagedata]);
```

In observer

```
$displayname = $observer->getData('obj');
        echo $displayname->getName(); exit;
```

But i am not getting data and getting getData on null error

Any thoughts ?

Update - i have override that class in my module & added another data object in dispatch & tried to get it

Comment: Need your thoughts on this guys.

Comment: Any thoughts ??

Comment: why add custom data in existing magento event? you can add any data in custom event.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing null because **customer_login** is the Magento default event and you can not dispatch another event with the same name. Try to change your event name.

Comment: Hello, i have override that class in my module & added another data object in dispatch & tried to get it.

Answer (score 0):

First get event then get data.

```
$observer->getEvent()->getData('obj');
```